# How to stop the effect of \balance{} command

Tags: vertical-alignment, two-column

I am using `\balance{}` command to balance the reference section. However,  I have appendix after the reference and I do not want balancing on the appendix.

How could I stop the effect of balancing after reference section?

Thanks

Comment: `\balance` isn't a standard command, what packages are you using?

Comment: According to documentation of the package `balance`  (I guess that's what you are using) there exists a `\nobalance` macro.

Comment: @campa I just came by this question and your suggestion using `\nobalance` resolved my problem. I guess you can post it as an answer.